# undefined method `admin?' when trying to add an admin user

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, boolean, admin

I have a Rails 3.2.2 application using Ruby version 1.9.2. I have created basic authentication  for my users by following the [tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch-revised) on Railscasts.

I don't need anything complicated, such as remember me or password resets and I would like to have a good understanding with what's actually going on before I look into using Devise or anything similar.

At the moment I have user accounts and I can check if the user is logged in by using

```
<% if current_user %>
```

So I would like to be able to do

```
<% if current_user.admin? %>
```

If I use the above `admin?` check I get the following error:

```
undefined method `admin?'
```

My understanding was that the above checks if the admin is true for the current user. I've added an admin column to my user table that's boolean and set to default = false.

```
create_table :users do |t|
  t.string :name
  t.string :initials
  t.string :email
  t.string :password_digest
  t.boolean :admin, :default => false
```

I have also added the admin column to my seed file so I can have a test admin account

```
User.create(name: 'Danny', initials: 'DAN', email: 'danny@railsapplication.co.uk', password: 'secret', admin: 'true')
```

As I have added an admin user, and I'm checking for the boolean value to be true I thought that would be all I needed to do.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  Is something not working like the `current_user.admin?` line or are you asking if your solution is sufficient?  If the latter, then yes, I think that's all you really need for a simple Admin user implementation.

Comment: I'll clarify the question; but the current_user.admin? results in a `undefined method `admin?'`

Comment: Have you run `rake db:migrate`? Your model doesn't think it has a boolean `admin` field.

Comment: Yeah, I've reset the database and the run `rake db:seed` which has pulled in the user accounts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've tried to add an `admin` column to your table by editing the original migration, you'll have to run `rake db:rollback` to drop the `users` table, and then `rake db:migrate` to bring the table back with the `admin` column in place.

You can't edit migrations this way and expect the results to appear in the database automatically. If you want to add columns to a table, you need to generate a second migration:

```
$ rails g migration AddAdminToUsers
```

And then use the `add_column` helper:

```
class AddAdminToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :admin, :boolean, :default => false
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm still working on the basics of the application so to keep the migrations as simple as possible I have altered the original migration and then dropped & recreated the database.

Comment: How have you recreated the database?

Comment: `rake db:drop` then `rake db:create && rake db:migrate`. I think this may be the problem, as the schema doesn't seem to show the admin column.

Comment: Although it's not throwing and error anymore it doesn't seem to have the expected effect. None of the users are admins. Is `admin: 'true'` the correct way to make my user an admin in the seed file?

Comment: If you're following any kind of best practice you've added `attr_accessable` and the `admin` field can't be mass-assigned. You should use `user.admin = true`.

Comment: After looking at the linked Railscast, they are indeed using `attr_accessable` to white list everything *but* the `admin` field, as they should. You won't be able to alter the `admin` field with the `User.new(attributes)`, `User.create(attributes)` or `update_attributes` methods.

Answer (score -2):

Edit: My mistake, ActiveRecord apparently should provide this.  Did you run your migration to update the schema?

You'll need to define the `admin?` method yourself.  I don't think ActiveRecord automatically provides a predicate style method for boolean attributes (though maybe there is a gem out there that does this?)

In your User model, just add:

```
def admin?
  admin
end
```

Or just use `current_user.admin`, which should do the same.  Though I kind of like the predicate look.

Comment: Adding the `def admin?` block to the User model results in `undefined local variable or method `admin'`.

Comment: Incorrect. ActiveRecord will provide an `admin?` accessor for the boolean `admin` attribute.